# Jira Cloud Filter: currentUser() mentioned in comment

Tags: filter, cloud, jira, jql

In Jira Cloud, I need to create a filter which shows all (open) issues where currentUser() is mentioned in comment.

I installed Adaptavist Script Runner plugin (Cloud version), and i can filter all issues commented by currentUser(), like

`commentedBy = currentUser()`

however, how do i filter all issues where currentUser() is mentioned in the comments field - i.e. @username blah blah... ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this JQL to search for all comments containing the current user's username: `comment ~ currentUser()`

Comment: I am using JIRA server but when I search this it returns nothing