# get a specific user's comments in Jira 8.5.0

Tags: jira, jql

I use Jira Server, I am trying to get a specific user's comments in advanced search with JQL. I don't want to use plug-ins. In other posts (which are mostly for Jira Cloud) I ve seen and I tried these:

`comment ~ "user.name"`, `comment ~ user.name`, `comment ~ currentUser()`, `comment ~ currentUser() OERDERBY createdDate DESC` or `issueFunction in commented("by user")`in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57691542/jira-cloud-filter-currentuser-mentioned-in-comment) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975529/issues-commented-by-me-in-jira/47118800) posts.

However none of these return a result, what I see is:

> No issues were found to match your search

Does anyone use Jira Software 8.5.0 Server and experienced such issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using issueFunction method and it does return me list of issues commented by an specific user.
For example, my user name is `vikkumar` then the syntax will look like this

```
issueFunction in commented("by vikkumar")
```

Let me know if this works.
Thanks.